How to get rid of $set in Vue 3 if first parameter is "this"?
Could you, please, tell how the following should be in Vue 3:
this.$set(this, 'model', this.entries[0])


$set used to be necessary because of the limitations of the Vue 2 reactivity system. No such limit exists in Vue 3. this.model = this.entries[0] is syntactically the equivalent code, though whether the code does what you expect is unknown as this could be XY problem. So if the code doesn't work, consider explaining the purpose of the code and what problem you're actually trying to solve.
